# Raise event handler in derived class

Tags: c#, events

Can anyone give solution?

```
public class BaseOne{
    public event EventHandler OperationChanged;
}

public class Derived: BaseOne
{
    private void OnChange(){
        if(OperationChanged!=null){
            OperationChanged(this,new EventArgs());
        }
    }
}

public Class MainClass
{
    public void Main()
    {
        Derived d = new Derived();
        d.OperationChanged += OnOperationChange;
    }

    private void OnOperationChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox("Hello I'm Called");
    }
}
```

I have tried like this, Can you suggest any better approach?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You have tried that, and is it not working? The code seems perfectly fine to me...

Comment: You have to **call OnChnage()** somewhere, do you think event will automatically raise?

Comment: What you want to achieve? what you wana do with it? or in other words What's wrong with it?

Comment: You spelled OnChnage wrong!!!

Comment: Hey I tried but it is showing error @OnChange() in Derived Class.
ERROR :
The event 'BaseOne.MoveNextPage' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -= (except when used from within the type 'BaseOne')

Comment: @Angloos : Error is : ERROR : The event 'BaseOne.MoveNextPage' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -= (except when used from within the type 'BaseOne')

Comment: First, You cannot directly fire base class events. Second, Change your method from private to Protected. Here a link to related matter https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy3sefw3(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: Thanks all, specially @Angloos, I have got work around as for now. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: there is a simple solution for this, change event handler field (OperationChanged) to property type. That's it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a new solution for this. Simple solution is to make field to Property...

```
using System;

class Base
{
    public event EventHandler OperationsChanged {get; set;}
}
class Derived : Base
{
   public void OnSpecificOperationChanged()
   {
        OperationsChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
   }
}

class Test
{
    static void  Main()
    {
        Derived d = new Derived();
       d.OperationsChanged += OnOperationsChanged;

       //invoke
       d.OnSpecificOperationChanged();

    } 
    static void OnOperationsChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("called");
    }
}
```

Comment: `{get; set;}`: An add or remove accessor expected.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot directly fire base class event.

A useful pattern to do this.

```
using System;

class Base
{
    public event EventHandler operationsChanged;
    public void OnOperationsChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        operationsChanged(this,e);
    }
}
class Derived : Base
{
    public void OnSpecificOperationChanged()
    {
        OnOperationsChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
class Test
{
    static void  Main()
    {
        Derived d = new Derived();
        d.operationsChanged += OnOperationsChanged;

        //invoke
        d.OnSpecificOperationChanged();

    }
    static void OnOperationsChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("called");
    }
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy3sefw3.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can we Optimize / is there any another pattern to solve this?

Comment: None that I know of.